# The purpose of lambda x: lambda: x

Tags: python, lambda, closures, interpreter

I was reading the code of byterun(a python python interpreter), and I can't understand lines below that something about closure and lambda:

```
def make_cell(value):
    fn = (lambda x: lambda: x)(value) 
    return fn.__closure__[0]
```

The function was called in The second to the last line:

```
class Function(object):
__slots__ = [... omit ...]

def __init__(self, name, code, globs, defaults, closure, vm):
    self._vm = vm
    self.func_code = code  
    self.func_name = self.__name__ = name or code.co_name  
    self.func_defaults = tuple(defaults)  
    self.func_globals = globs  
    self.func_locals = self._vm.frame.f_locals  
    self.__dict__ = {}  
    self.func_closure = closure  
    self.__doc__ = code.co_consts[0] if code.co_consts else None  
    kw = {
        'argdefs': self.func_defaults,
    }
    if closure:
        kw['closure'] = tuple(make_cell(0) for _ in closure)
    self._func = types.FunctionType(code, globs, **kw)
```

What's the function's purpose? And how does it work(especially with 2 lambda)?

Comment: It's not very clear given the 3 line context. Link to the source code where `make_cell` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this `lambda x: lambda: x` construct is to create a [closure cell object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/cell.html), the objects Python uses to implement closure variables. The nested `lambda: x` uses the `x` variable from the outer `lambda`, so Python needs to create a closure cell for the `x` variable. Calling the outer lambda:

```
(lambda x: lambda: x)(value)
```

creates a function object for the inner `lambda` with a closure cell for the `x` variable holding `value`, and the `__closure__` access:

```
return fn.__closure__[0]
```

accesses the function object's tuple of closure variables to retrieve and return the closure cell.

Comment: And the function was called：tuple(make_cell(0) for _ in closure). Does it return the argument 0 ? Still confused. :(

Comment: @kaka4NERV: `fn` *would* return 0 if called, but the cell *containing* that 0 is returned instead.